# rosws not adding workspace directory to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-precise, virtualbox, rosws, ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am doing the setup tutorial on the ros website (not allowing me to post links...) I'm running a fresh install of the Ubuntu 12.04 ROS image from NooTriX in VirtualBox right now.

My problem is on section 4.2 of the tutorial where it tells you to do:

```
rosws set ~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox
```

I am running groovy and made a different directory, so I did:

```
rosws set ~/groovy_workspace/sandbox
```

The error I get is:

```
viki@ROS:~$ rosws set ~/groovy_workspace/sandbox
ERROR in config: Command requires a target workspace.viki@ROS:~$
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? I've already done:

```
source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash
```

and

```
rosws init ~/fuerte_workspace /opt/ros/fuerte
```

and

```
source /home/viki/groovy_workspace/setup.bash
```

When I look at my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, all I see is

```
:/opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks
```

So I am guessing something is wrong with rosws adding the right directories to the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. Does anyone have any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55072/rosws-not-adding-workspace-directory-to-ros_package_path/) by [w1res](https://answers.ros.org/users/4186/w1res/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a bug in rosws when used with groovy that makes it harder to `roscd` without arguments to get to your workspace. Instead, you need to `cd ~/groovy_workspace` and *then* you can execute `rosws set`.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2013-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [w1res](https://answers.ros.org/users/4186/w1res/) on 2013-02-14**:
It seems like this makes rosws set work, but it seems like the ROS_WORKSPACE still remains unset.

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-02-14**:
Yes, you will need to manually export `ROS_WORKSPACE` until the bugfix gets out through the debian packages.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After you run

```
 rosws init /home/viki/groovy_workspace /opt/ros/groovy
 source /home/viki/groovy_workspace/setup.bash
```

what you should get is:

```
$ echo $ROS_WORKSPACE
/home/viki/groovy_workspace
$ echo ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks
```

due to bug already fixed but not released yet, ROS_WORKSPACE is not set. See:
http://answers.ros.org/question/54871/no-ros_workspace-set-error/

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-02-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1